# И еще о литературной речи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Слово "дотуда" мне всегда казалось сугубо разговорным и не очень грамотным. Но теперь я иногда слышу его и с экрана телевизора. Разве это литературное слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словарях слово **дотуда**, а также и  слова **докуда, докуда-нибудь** помечаются как разговорные. А то, что они широко употребляются (даже с экрана телевизора), - неудивительно. Границы между стилями речи сейчас не такие жесткие, непроницаемые, как это было раньше. Смесь французского с нижегородским нынче выдается за правильную речь.